# What happens to my characters if I close my Tera account?

Tags: tera

Before I spend $50 or more on Tera, I'd like to know what happens to my characters if (when) I decide to quit.  Can I come back at a later time and pick up where I left off or do the characters just get deleted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you buy the game, play, then cancel your subscription, **the characters are retained indefinitely**. If you decide to play *TERA* again after cancelling an account, you'll be able to pick up where you left off.

Comment: In addition to this, should they ever decide to wipe characters it will be only on accounts inactive over a certain amount of time and it will be announced a few weeks ahead of time with emails so you know.